# End of support dates for .NET Framework versions that are "components" of Windows

Tags: .net

This [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/548) lists end of support dates for versions of .NET.  But from .NET 4.5.2 on it just says this on each one.

> .NET Framework is a component of the Windows OS. Components receive the same support as their parent product or platform.For more information, please visit the .NET Framework Lifecycle FAQ.

It does not say which Windows version the .NET version is a component of (and nor does the FAQ).

I need to be able to plan for the end of support for these versions of .NET, but I am very confused on how to find out when they will end support for them.

Here is my question:

- How can I find which version of windows a given version of .NET is attached to?
- Once I know that, how I can find the end of support for that version of windows?

NOTE: I have tried searching for this, and the best I can find is a table on Wikipedia.  While helpful, I would like to have an official Microsoft source (site) for this information.

Comment: Best to ask on the dotnet/runtime GitHub, methinks.

Comment: Just google for “windows end of support dates”: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet

Comment: And the framework-to-OS bindings are apparent from this FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework

Comment: @OndrejTucny - Exactly what I was looking for!  Post as answer and I will accept.  Thank you!